# How to save pdf and videos file to device file system, NOT application directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

So i was wondering if theres a way to save a pdf and videos (or other types of files) to the device so that the user can open it in iBooks, iTunes or other such apps. I know you're able to save images in photos since I already did this and thought maybe it was possible with other types of files.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the file to the File system itself and then use `UIDocumentPickerController` to open the file in whatever application you want.
By using `UIDocumentPickerController` you open a popop which has all the applications that can open the file, and when you choose an application, the file gets copied to "THAT" application's directory.